# What are these invisible egg blocks?

Tags: super-mario-bros-wonder

Occasionally in Super Mario Wonder I'll hit an invisible block with an egg on it.  What are these invisible egg blocks for? How are they different from regular invisible coin blocks?

[image: Revealed red egg block]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are character-specific blocks that turn visible if you get close while playing as the specific character.
The egg blocks are for the differently colored Yoshis.

Just like normal invisible blocks, any character can hit them if you know where they are.

[image]