# Is there any difference between Super Mario Wonder's characters?

Tags: super-mario-bros-wonder

The game explains that choosing any Yoshi or Nabbit lets you play an easier version since you can't be damaged. But what about the other characters? In *Super Mario 3D World* each one had a special trait, are they just identical in *Super Mario Wonder*?

The only thing that actually changes seems to be that, when playing with a different character, [special invisible blocks become visible](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/404921/what-are-these-invisible-egg-blocks).

Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no differences between the physics of all of the characters. Jump height, speed, size, and any other attributes are the same for all characters.
The only *true* differences are with Yoshis and Nabbit, which (as you point out) cannot take damage, and the fact that Yoshis can do Yoshi things (such as be ridden and fly).

Comment: You can ride a friend Yoshi in multiplayer? Cool!

Answer (score 4):

According to [the Super Bros. Wonder Mario Direct](https://youtu.be/G0m_uNaSres?t=229) (3:45), aside from the Yoshis and Nabbit, each character plays identically.

> Besides Mario, you can also play as Luigi, Peach, Daisy, one of two Toads, and Toadette. **They all play the same**, so go with your favorite or mix it up. **The Yoshis and Nabbit, on the other hand, won't take damage**. They're a great choice if you're looking for a more easy-going experience.

To be more specific, aside from the [character-specific invisible blocks](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/404922/181240), there are 3 categories of character playstyle.

- Mario, Luigi, Peach, Daisy, Yellow Toad, Blue Toad, Toadette

  - Can use powerups
  - Take damage from enemies/obstacles
- Yoshi, Red Yoshi, Yellow Yoshi, Light-Blue Yoshi

  - Cannot use powerups
  - Does not take damage from enemies/obstacles
  - Can Flutter Jump
  - Can eat objects and spit them out with tongue
  - Other players can ride on Yoshi's back in multiplayer
- Nabbit

  - Cannot use powerups, but turns them into coins
  - Does not flinch or take damage from enemies/obstacles

Comment: Yeah I kinda remember that statement, thank you for providing an official answer